# php.ini - How to recover pdo.so?

Tags: centos, php53

I recently installed memcached. Everything worked swimmingly until I restarted the system. I have no idea what went wrong, but after the restart, some files were missing. Main main problem is that I have pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so files missing.

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320644/how-do-i-enable-pdo-using-centos). This lead me to the following error:

```
Warning: dl(): Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' -
  /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: 
    cannot open shared object file: 
      No such file or directory in /root/tmp/moduleEnabled.php on line 6
```

I can't run:

```
pecl install PDO
```

... because it ends with a huge error that I think is as a result of PDO actually being installed, but the files being missing or deleted.

I ran:

```
find / -name pdo.so
```

And it came back with nothing. I ran the same command on another server, and it returned:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so
```

However, I also read this: "Do not use this, as PDO has been moved into core (the php source) so this pecl extension is dead." ... [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO), which leads me to believe that with PHP version 5.3.22 I no longer need to install PECL. If this is so, why is the extension not working when I enable it in php.ini?

PhpInfo says this:

```
Configure Command    './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '**--disable-pdo**' 
'--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
'--enable-intl' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' 
'--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' 
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' 
'--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' 
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' 
'--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' 
'--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' 
'--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' 
'--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pic' 
'--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' 
'--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Clearly PDO is still disabled. Must I recompile PHP to enable it, perhaps? How do I do that?

Based on the the above, can anyone please advise me on how to get PDO to work with PHP 5.3.22 on my Centos Box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I installed PDO manually on a cPanel server. To fix the problem I simply selected the modules I needed in WHM and the problem was fixed.